# WEBRTC - screen sharing without any extensions

Tags: javascript, typescript, webrtc

I have simple question. Is there any possibility to implement screen sharing which will work on most of devices and browsers?

I look on the internet, and found some plugins for chrome, but I want to have screen sharing without installing any plugins, or setting some experimental flag on chrome.

The best solution will be when I could have stream from navigator, the same as my camera-capture.

Code for getting video from camera

```
this.navig.getUserMedia =  ( this.navig.getUserMedia || this.navig.webkitGetUserMedia || this.navig.mozGetUserMedia || this.navig.msGetUserMedia );
this.navig.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, (stream) => {
        this.videoElement.nativeElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        this.videoElement.nativeElement.play();
}, (error) => console.warn('video error' + error))
```

so I want to have stream object with my screen captured. Is that possible?

I found this on internet, but this returns me some errors...

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true })
.then(stream => {
    // we have a stream, attach it to a feedback video element
    videoElement.srcObject = stream;
  }, error => {
    console.log("Unable to acquire screen capture", error);
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2019 update: yes, it's possible.
Works on Chrome, Firefox and Safari using [getDisplayMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia)

```
let displayMediaOptions = {video: true, audio: false};
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions)
.then(function(stream){
  video_el.srcObject = stream;
})
```

Working demo at: [thescreenshare.com](https://thescreenshare.com/)

Answer (score 2):

At this stage only firefox will let you use screensharing without an additional security plugin or service.